# How can I turn on my computer and bypass the password with Android

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, android

I am travelling overseas but would like to be able to remotely turn on and control my computer (Win7) from my Android (i9500 jtxx on 4.3 rooted) phone. My computer is currently password protected, and I would like for this to remain the case.

Comment: So what would be the problem with **any** of the [RDP-based Apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rdp&c=apps) from the Play Store? The part of "Turn On" has nothing to do with bypassing password. You could do that with WOL.

Comment: If you are already away, there is very likely nothing you can do to configure the PC to accept remote connections, let alone turn on, without you physically being at the PC to set it up. If you haven't left yet, what have you researched/tried?

Comment: I am not away yet and have been trying to, but couldn't find a way to bypass password with wake on lan

Comment: Are you saying your computer has a power on password? If so, I don't know of any way to get around that remotely.

Comment: what is a power on password?

Comment: @kappa "power on password" is a password in the bios. You should be able to easily distinguish it from the windows password. Bios password screen is usually just text based while the windows password screen is graphical. Otherwise post a screenshot or photo.